# ArcGIS JS API: make circle not zoom

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a ArcGIS JavaScript API map. On map click I want to display a circle and highlight all the points within that circle.

However, when I create the circle and zoom in the map, the circle zooms in as well. How can I get the circle to stay the same pixel radius no matter what the zoom level of the map?

```js
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/widgets/Zoom",
            "esri/core/watchUtils",
            "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"
        ], function (Map, GeoJSONLayer, MapView, Zoom, watchUtils, {buffer}) {
            const url =
                    "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson";

            const template = {
                title: "Earthquake Info",
                content: "Magnitude {mag} {type} hit {place} on {time}",
                fieldInfos: [
                    {
                        fieldName: "time",
                        format: {
                            dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };

            const renderer = {
                type: "simple",
                field: "mag",
                symbol: {
                    type: "simple-marker",
                    color: "orange",
                    outline: {
                        color: "white"
                    }
                },
                visualVariables: [
                    {
                        type: "size",
                        field: "mag",
                        stops: [
                            {
                                value: 2.5,
                                size: "4px"
                            },
                            {
                                value: 8,
                                size: "40px"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };

            const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
                url: url,
                copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
                popupTemplate: template,
                renderer: renderer //optional
            });

            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray",
                layers: [geojsonLayer]
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                center: [-168, 46],
                zoom: 3,
                map: map
            });

            let csvLayerView;
            let highlight;
            let resultFeatures;

            view.whenLayerView(geojsonLayer).then(layerView => {
                csvLayerView = layerView;
            });

            view.on("click", ({mapPoint}) => {
                const geom = buffer(mapPoint, 500, "miles");

                view.graphics.removeAll();
                view.graphics.add({
                    geometry: geom,
                    symbol: {
                        type: "simple-fill",
                        color: [51, 51, 204, 0.2],
                        style: "solid",
                        outline: {
                            color: "white",
                            width: 1
                        }
                    }
                });

                const query = geojsonLayer.createQuery();
                query.geometry = geom;
                csvLayerView.queryObjectIds(query).then(oids => {
                    if (highlight) {
                        highlight.remove();
                    }
                    highlight = csvLayerView.highlight(oids);
                    return csvLayerView.queryFeatures(query);
                }).then(({features}) => {
                    resultFeatures = features;
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The circle that you create, using a 500 miles buffer of the click point, is a polygon. So naturally will be the same one no matter what zoom level you have. In other words, represent a geographic area so it can not change based on the zoom level.

On contrary, in the same example you have the points that represent the earthquakes, that are represented with a orange circle. Because it is a symbol that represents a geographic place, it keeps the size in pixels for all zoom levels.

Resuming, you can not make the 500 miles buffer area, represented by the polygon, to change with the zoom levels, because it is an area.